# How to view HTML file in android Web view?

Tags: android, webview

I have web view in my application and I want to load my local html file inside that web view
Is it possible and how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer from [here](http://www.monocube.com/2011/02/08/android-tutorial-html-file-in-webview/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following:

```
WebView webView = . . .;
File localFile = . . .;
webView.loadUrl(localFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

If your html is a string resource, it can be loaded into the web view like this:

```
webView.loadData(getResources().getString(R.string.html), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

(where `R.string.html` is the resource ID of your html). If your html is stored in the assets folder or as a raw resource, you can load it into a string using the method shown in the link that @Krishna posted.